# OpenGL ES 2.0 perspective projection -> cube is rectangular

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

**[SOLVED - See answer in bottom]**

I'm trying to draw a cube with perspective, using *OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS (iPhone)*, but it's appearing as a rectangular shape.

From what I've gathered searching the web it seems to be related to the viewport / projection matrix, but I can't seem to put the finger on the actual cause.

If I set the viewport to a square measure (width == height) it draws perfectly well (a cube), but if I set it correctly (width = screen_width, height = screen_height) then the cube is drawn as a rectangular shape.

Should setting the Projection matrix accordingly with the Viewport make the cube stay a cube?!

My code (please let me know if more info is needed):

**Render method:**

```
// viewportSize is SCREEN_WIDTH and SCREEN_HEIGHT
// viewportLowerLeft is 0.0 and 0.0
ivec2 size = this->viewportSize;
ivec2 lowerLeft = this->viewportLowerLeft;
glViewport(lowerLeft.x, lowerLeft.y, size.x, size.y); // if I put size.x, size.x it draws well


mat4 projectionMatrix = mat4::FOVFrustum(45.0, 0.1, 100.0, size.x / size.y);

glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms.Projection, 1, 0, projectionMatrix.Pointer());
```

**Matrix operations:**

```
static Matrix4<T> Frustum(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T near, T far)
{
    T a = 2 * near / (right - left);
    T b = 2 * near / (top - bottom);
    T c = (right + left) / (right - left);
    T d = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    T e = - (far + near) / (far - near);
    T f = -2 * far * near / (far - near);
    Matrix4 m;
    m.x.x = a; m.x.y = 0; m.x.z = 0; m.x.w = 0;
    m.y.x = 0; m.y.y = b; m.y.z = 0; m.y.w = 0;
    m.z.x = c; m.z.y = d; m.z.z = e; m.z.w = -1;
    m.w.x = 0; m.w.y = 0; m.w.z = f; m.w.w = 1;
    return m;
}
static Matrix4<T> FOVFrustum(T fieldOfView, T near, T far, T aspectRatio)
{
    T size = near * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(fieldOfView) / 2.0);
    return Frustum(-size, size, -size / aspectRatio, size / aspectRatio, near, far);
}
```

Comment: What is the ratio in the last parameter of the FOVFrustum constructor meant to do? It seems like your issue might be there.

Comment: @jakev: I don't follow, how am I supposed to calculate the FOV Frustum without it? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Can the order of matrix multiplication or something like that be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out the problem, size.x and size.y are int, so the division returns an int.

```
1.0 * size.x / size.y
```

Solves the problem.
*facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured this out already, change:

```
return Frustum(-size, size, -size / aspectRatio, size / aspectRatio, near, far);
```

to

```
return Frustum(-size / aspectRatio, size / aspectRatio, -size, size,, near, far);
```

and it should draw correctly.
(or simply change the ratio from size.x/size.y to size.y/size.x)

Comment: Switching the .x and .y was one of the first things I did, it just makes the cube not even appear on screen. I tried switching the Frustum function parameters as you suggested and it resulted in the same thing.

Comment: Try setting the 3rd argument of glUniformMatrix4fv to true

Comment: With the 3rd argument True, the cube no longer shows (and I have it in a cyclic movement in all axis). The problem seems to be somewhere else, but I really don't know where to look.